# glxgears/OpenGL segmentation fault

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, opengl

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in a Asus desktop with onboard Intel graphics. This installation was somehow old (maybe 17.04), that I've been updating every new release; and also used it as LiveUSB in other two hardware, before using definitive here.

Everything seems working fine, beside I can't use VLC with OpenGL. In VLC menu Tools\Preferences\Video, I need to set Output=X11 (XCB). OpenGL gets segmentation fault.

After further investigation, I realized that glxgears also breaks with segmentation fault. I believe that I have already reinstalled all possible drivers and packages. Booting with Live USB or using a Lubuntu installation that I have on an external disk, glxgears and VLC work without problems, so there must be a problem with this Ubuntu installation and not with the hardware. The following commands in terminal are almost the same in those three OSs.

I'm stuck on a wall. I appreciate help of what else I can try, if needed I can send more information. I really didn't want to have to reinstall everything from scratch.

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxxx 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series) (rev 02)

$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8

$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.7 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 20.1.1 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD


$ apt list *xorg*
Listing... Pronto
fcitx5-module-xorg/focal 0.0~git20200128.9e3bc8d+ds1-3 amd64
libxorg-gtest-data/focal,focal 0.7.1-5ubuntu1 all
libxorg-gtest-dev/focal,focal 0.7.1-5ubuntu1 all
libxorg-gtest-doc/focal,focal 0.7.1-5ubuntu1 all
tigervnc-xorg-extension/focal 1.10.1+dfsg-3 amd64
xorg-dev/focal,focal 1:7.7+19ubuntu14 all
xorg-docs-core/focal,focal,now 1:1.7.1-1.1 all [installed,automatic]
xorg-docs/focal,focal 1:1.7.1-1.1 all
xorg-server-source-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xorg-server-source/focal-updates,focal-updates 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 all
xorg-sgml-doctools/focal,focal,now 1:1.11-1 all [installed,automatic]
xorg/focal,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu14 amd64 [installed]
xorgxrdp/focal 1:0.2.12-1 amd64
xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-core/focal-updates,now 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-core/focal-updates 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 i386
xserver-xorg-dev-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-dev/focal-updates 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 amd64
xserver-xorg-dev/focal-updates 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 i386
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-all/focal,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu14 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dbg/focal 1:2.10.6-1 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev/focal,focal 1:2.10.6-1 all
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04-dbg/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-evdev/focal,now 1:2.10.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev/focal,focal 1:1.6.3-1build1 all
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-joystick/focal 1:1.6.3-1build1 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-kbd/focal 1:1.9.0-1build1 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev/focal,focal 0.29.0-1 all
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-libinput/focal,now 0.29.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-input-mouse/focal 1:1.9.3-1build1 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-mtrack-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-mtrack/focal 0.3.1-1build2 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-multitouch/focal 1.0~rc3-2 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev/focal,focal 1.9.1-1ubuntu3 all
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/focal,now 1.9.1-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-input-void/focal 1:1.4.1-1build3 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-input-wacom/focal,now 1:0.39.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-input-xwiimote/focal 0.5-1build3 amd64
xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-legacy/focal-updates,now 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-legacy/focal-updates 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2 i386
xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-all/focal,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu14 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/focal,now 19.1.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-ati/focal,now 1:19.1.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-dummy-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-dummy/focal 1:0.3.8-1build3 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev/focal,now 1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-intel/focal,now 2:2.99.917+git20200226-1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-mga/focal 1:2.0.0-1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/focal,now 1:1.0.16-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390/focal-updates,focal-security 390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390/focal-updates,focal-security 390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418-server/focal-updates 418.152.00-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418/focal 430.50-0ubuntu3 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430/focal-updates,focal-security 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435/focal 435.21-0ubuntu7 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440-server/focal-updates 440.95.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440/focal-updates,focal-security 440.100-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/focal 1:0.6.0-3build1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-qxl/focal,now 0.1.5+git20200331-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-radeon/focal,now 1:19.1.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-vesa/focal,now 1:2.4.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04/focal 3:14.5 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-vmware/focal,now 1:13.3.0-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg/focal,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu14 amd64 [installed,automatic]

$ apt list mesa*
Listing... Pronto
mesa-common-dev/focal-updates,now 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
mesa-common-dev/focal-updates 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 i386
mesa-opencl-icd/focal-updates 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 amd64
mesa-opencl-icd/focal-updates 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 i386
mesa-utils-extra/focal 8.4.0-1build1 amd64
mesa-utils/focal,now 8.4.0-1build1 amd64 [installed]
mesa-va-drivers/focal-updates,now 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mesa-va-drivers/focal-updates 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 i386
mesa-vdpau-drivers/focal-updates 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 amd64
mesa-vdpau-drivers/focal-updates 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 i386
mesa-vulkan-drivers/focal-updates,now 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mesa-vulkan-drivers/focal-updates,now 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]

$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
OpenGL version string:  4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes

$ glxgears -info
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
GL_RENDERER   = Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
GL_VERSION    = 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
GL_VENDOR     = Intel
GL_EXTENSIONS = GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_fragment_shader GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_fog_distance GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query GL_OES_EGL_image GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object GL_AMD_texture_texture4 GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_conservative_depth GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_ARB_compatibility GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_EXT_direct_state_access GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_AMD_query_buffer_object GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_copy_image GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_robustness GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_AMD_pinned_memory GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts GL_ARB_indirect_parameters GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters GL_ARB_shader_group_vote GL_ARB_shading_language_include GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted GL_ARB_cull_distance GL_ARB_derivative_control GL_ARB_direct_state_access GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_ARB_fragment_shader_interlock GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64 GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile GL_ARB_post_depth_coverage GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops GL_ARB_shader_ballot GL_ARB_shader_clock GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_NV_fragment_shader_interlock GL_ARB_gl_spirv GL_ARB_spirv_extensions GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod GL_INTEL_shader_atomic_float_minmax GL_INTEL_shader_integer_functions2 GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives GL_EXT_EGL_sync GL_EXT_demote_to_helper_invocation 
VisualID 300, 0x12c
Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)

$ glmark2
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
    GL_VERSION:    4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 4274 FrameTime: 0.234 ms
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 4274 
=======================================================

$ ldd /usr/bin/glxgears
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc56743000)
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x00007f3a00d02000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f3a00c7a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3a00b2b000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f3a009ee000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3a007fc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3a007f6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3a007d1000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f3a00719000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f3a006e5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3a00f43000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f3a006bb000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f3a006b5000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f3a006ab000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f3a00691000)

$ valgrind glxgears
==99649== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==99649== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==99649== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==99649== Command: glxgears
==99649== 

...

==99649== 
==99649== Invalid write of size 8
==99649==    at 0x4842AD9: memmove (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==99649==    by 0x638A2FF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x5E80C55: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x598C0C6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x598BB27: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x597DC49: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x5B48160: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x5A0F54A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x5A31A79: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x10B1BB: ??? (in /usr/bin/glxgears)
==99649==    by 0x10AC87: ??? (in /usr/bin/glxgears)
==99649==    by 0x4DBC0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==99649==  Address 0x7f2e1a4792a0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==99649== 
==99649== Invalid write of size 2
==99649==    at 0x4842B33: memmove (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==99649==    by 0x6391B34: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x6689FEE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x597DBC6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x5B48160: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x5A0F54A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x5A31A79: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so)
==99649==    by 0x10B1BB: ??? (in /usr/bin/glxgears)
==99649==    by 0x10AC87: ??? (in /usr/bin/glxgears)
==99649==    by 0x4DBC0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==99649==  Address 0x7f2e1a715bf8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==99649== 
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
==99649== 
==99649== HEAP SUMMARY:
==99649==     in use at exit: 2,398,721 bytes in 9,054 blocks
==99649==   total heap usage: 16,738 allocs, 7,684 frees, 6,086,266 bytes allocated
==99649== 
==99649== LEAK SUMMARY:
==99649==    definitely lost: 88 bytes in 3 blocks
==99649==    indirectly lost: 272 bytes in 4 blocks
==99649==      possibly lost: 343,991 bytes in 1,332 blocks
==99649==    still reachable: 2,054,370 bytes in 7,715 blocks
==99649==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==99649== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==99649== 
==99649== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==99649== ERROR SUMMARY: 6296 errors from 598 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is to look at `ldd` output for `glxgears` to see what it is using. For me, also on Ubuntu 20.04, it looks like this:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/glxgears
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd80d06000)
libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f5544534000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f55443e5000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f55442a8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f55440b6000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f5543ffe000)
libGLX.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f5543fca000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f55445e4000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5543f9e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5543f98000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f5543f92000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f5543f8a000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f5543f70000)
```

The libraries listed there might be important, you could check if you happen to have an unusual version installed for one of those for some reason.

Another thing you could try is to run `glxgears` through `valgrind` like this:

```
valgrind glxgears
```

Then `valgrind` should show you some info about where the segmentation fault happens, that could be useful.

You can try to install packages with debugging symbols included (or build from source yourself with the -g compiler option turned on) to allow valgrind to show more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, I've include ldd output and partial valgrind output in the question. valgrind shows a lot of "Invalid write", not sure what this means. Check also my FailsafeX answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has fallen here with the same problem: I went into recovery mode and FailsafeX, I didn't change anything, I only ran it once and then I went back to normal mode. With that VLC and glxgears returned to work normally. Somehow Ubuntu fixed the flaws on its own.

Comment: Interesting. When you say "ran it once", do you mean you ran glxgears once, or just that you entered recovery mode once? Did you do anything while in recovery mode that could have made a difference?

Comment: I've entered once recovery mode, it took a long time, so I shut it down and got back to normal mode because I needed to work. Then I ran glxgears and it was fine. If I run glxgears and VLC now, they are fine.